# How to handle error sign in message on devise with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise

I've add Ajax to my sign in form and it's work nice when I enter a true informations, but when I enter something wrong I can't handle the error message.

#### sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:destroy, :create]

  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

#### sign in form

```
<div class="sign_in_modal">
  <div class="modal fade" id="sign_in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sign_in">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_session_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :username, 'Username' %>
              <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control txt-main', id: 'sign_in_auto_focus' %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %>
              <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control txt-main' %>
            </div>

            <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
              <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
              <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Save your login?' %>
            <% end -%>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <%= f.submit "Login", class: 'btn btn-main btn-md' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### create.js.erb

```
$('.sign_in_modal .modal').modal('hide');
$('.header h1').after('<p class="username"><%= current_user.username.capitalize %></p>');
$('.sign_up_and_in').remove();
$('.navbar-nav').append('<li><a tabindex="-1" title="Edit Account Setting" href="/users/edit"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i><span style="display: none;"  class="cog-text">Edit Account Setting</span></a></li>');
$('.navbar-nav').append('<li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i><span style="display: none;" class="sign-out-text">LogOut</span>'), destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :tabindex => -1, title: "LogOut" %></li>');
```

How can I handle the error message in this case?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Sam || I mean the error message that show when the user enter a wrong informations

Comment: Did you mean how do you add the devise given error message by using the  Js you have in `create.js.erb` ?

Comment: @Arup Rakshit || I mean how to show message say to the user that he is enter a wrong username or password when he do

Comment: Devise use [this helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb#L4) to show any devise controller related error messages.. So you need to use the same in your JS.. Like `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`

Comment: @Arup Rakshit || That is work only if the user enter true username and password, but if the user enter wrong data the JS don't be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem by override new action on sessions controller like this:

```
def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And make file `new.js.erb` under `devise/sessions`, if user enter true username and password will login and if enter a wrong username or password the `new.js.erb` file will run and show wrong data message.